# Testing an instance variable in a Sinatra route

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, sinatra

I need to test a route like the bellow, in a Sinatra app.

```
post '/xxx' do

    @yyy.update do |doc|
        ...
        ...
        ...
    end

redirect '/zzz'

end
```

My problem is: how can I create the variable @yyy (in this case a class) and the method 'update', from my tests?

Comment: Where does `@yyy` come from in your route?

Comment: Hi Phrogz. The variable @yyy comes from another route, GET '/xxx'.

Comment: Instance variables set in out route handler are not available for usage in a separate route handler.